# Population of a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a code to populate a Numpy array. It's a 2D array, so I run two For loops with a specified condition. "Coords" array are positions of my particles. However every time I try to run it through the loops "coords" array starts being populated from x=2 position rather than x=1 (so the second position from the array) and then it gives me an error because of the lack of space in the array. Any ideas why is this happening? 
Thank you for any help!

The error I am getting:

"IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10"

Here's my code:

```
import random
from math import exp, pow
import numpy as np



#Lattice and sampling parameters:

L = 10 #no of sites per one side of the lattice
nSites = L*L
nPart = 10 #no of particles
nSteps = 50000
AddRemFraction = 0.5 #acceptance ratio    
# create an array of coordinates of particles:
    coords = np.zeros((nPart,2), dtype=object)

    # create an LxL array of particle occupancy => occ(x,y) = 1 if site is occupied
    occ = np.zeros((L, L), dtype=object)

    #no of particles that have been placed on the lattice so far
    nPlace = 0 

    for x in range (1,  L):
        for y in range (1, L):
            if (nPlace < nPart):
                nPlace = nPlace +1
                coords[nPlace,:] = [x,y]
                occ[x,y]=1
```

Comment: Indexing starts at 0 (different than Matlab and Julia). Are you aware of that? (and add the full stack-trace error.output to your question)

Comment: Why are you using object arrays?

Comment: @sascha  how do I add stack-trace error output?

Comment: @percusse isn't that the easiest way to do that? (I am pretty new with Python)

Comment: Convert your `range(1, L)`s into `range(L)`s and also move the line `nPlace = nPlace +1` to the end. But still I don't know what this should do. It's guaranteed to give you the first row of ones and rest is zero

Comment: @kamilsparrow, @sascha already gave you your answer, use `range (0,  L)` instead of  `range(1,L)` for both loops. Arrays and lists in most programming languages start from 0 not from 1 (that also means that last position of the array is L-1, L doesn't exist and will give an error).

Comment: @kamilsparrow You just copy the whole output of your error (no special machinery needed; many lines) and format it as code in your question. There is usually a lot of info available (and *lack of space in the array* is not an error-message numpy gives; at least not these words).

Comment: I think @sascha is assuming that you are getting an error, in which case you just copy and paste the error... in your case, you should always copy and paste the output you are getting, and the output you wish so people in stackoverflow has less trouble understanding your question...

Comment: @percusse Changing that fixes the "occ" array problem however the "coords" array is still populated from the second position and with all x's equal to 0 rather than 1. I am kind of clueless here